# Does std::future spin-wait?

Tags: c++, c++11, promise, future

Before explaining the question in more detail, I'll note that the answer is obviously implementation dependent, so I'm primarily asking about libstdc++, but I would also be interested in hearing about libc++.  The operating system is Linux.

Calling `wait()` or `get()` on a `std::future` blocks until the result is set by an asynchronous operation -- either an `std::promise`, `std::packaged_task`, or `std::asyn` function.  The availability of the result is communicated through a *shared state*, which is basically an atomic variable: the future waits for the shared state to be marked as ready by the promise (or async task).  This waiting and notification is implemented in libstdc++ via a *futex* system call.  Granted that futexes are highly performant, in situations where a future expects to only wait for an extremely brief period (on the order of single microseconds), it would seem that a performance gain could be made by spinning on the shared state for a short time before proceeding to wait on the futex.

I have not found any evidence of such spinning in the current implementation, however, I did find a comment in [atomic_futex.h at line 161](https://gcc.gnu.org/viewcvs/gcc/trunk/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/atomic_futex.h?revision=243994&view=markup#l161) where I would expect to find such spinning:

```
// TODO Spin-wait first.
```

So my question is rather the following: Are there really plans to implement a spin-wait, and if so, how will the duration be decided?  Additionally, is this the type of functionality that could eventually be specified through a policy to the future?

Comment: It's an implementation detail. It might be a small-wait optimization to spin-wait for a number of tries, and then actually wait (get taken off the CPU)

Comment: I think, it is not relevant on Linux, since mutex system call on Linux is actually a futex.

Comment: @SergeyA Still, a futex call can take several micros, whereas spinning can be only several nanos.  I realize it's an optimization for a very specific use case.

Comment: @SpectralSequence, why? Would be the same thing exactly.

Comment: @SergeyA actually the spinning checks an atomic variable, it doesn't use a mutex

Comment: @SpectralSequence but mutex in linux is spin-checking atomic variable for some time followed by system call. It's no different from hand-crafted spinning.

Comment: The `std::future` API does not allow setting a spin policy and would need to be changed. I don't recall anyone in the standards body discussing implementing such a thing (I'm not sure why they would -- `std::future<T>` sucks for performance anyway).

Comment: @TravisGockel can you elaborate about the poor performance?

Comment: The problem is `future` only allows interaction via blocking calls (`get`, `wait`, etc). In a real application, you would want a mechanism to fire the next step of the process as soon as the result is ready. `std::experimental::future` begins to address this with `then` and `is_ready`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I will answer the question: Does `std::future::get()` perform a spin-wait?

The answer for all of C++ is: It is an implementation detail. A conforming standard library might spin or it might not (in the same vein, `std::mutex::lock()` is allowed to spin). Will there be a mechanism for specifying if and how to spin in the future? The places to look are in [`std::experimental::future`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/future) (coming to a full version of the Standard Library soon), [`boost::future`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.futures) (proving ground for what might later go into the standard), and [`hpx::future`](http://stellar-group.github.io/hpx/docs/html/hpx/manual/lcos/extend_futures.html) (performance-focused library with advanced facilities for `future` management). None of these have mechanisms for explicit specification of spinning, nor has there been discussion in meeting minutes that I know of nor on the ISO CPP mailing list. It is safe to say that something like a `get_with_spins` function is not in the pipeline.

To answer for `libstdc++` (and `libc++`): They also do not spin. Aside from the TODO which came from [the original patch](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/libstdc++/2015-01/msg00076.html), it does not look like there is any plan to change this. I've searched the GCC mailing list for mentions of changing this behavior, but found none. Doing a pre-sleep spin can hurt in the general case (if none of the `get()`s have a value, you've wasted a lot of CPU cycles), so a change here could have negative impacts.

To summarize: Implementations do not appear to spin now and there appear to be no plans to change the behavior in the near future, but that can change at any moment.